# SharePoint multi user access

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am new to SharePoint and wanted to know if multiple users can access and use a group calendar.  I know that SharePoint uses MS SQL to store the data and SQL can be accessed by multiple users.  In the unlikely case when two or more users access the same group calendar that is set up for reserving resources, can they all make reservations or will only the first person that accesses the site be able to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint is a collaboration tool, meant for multiple users to access everything at the same time. Your calendar can be accessed by X amount of users, simultaneously. Individual identities are not passed onto SQL, the SharePoint site's web application pool identity is used to access SQL.

HTH

Comment: Would the calendar be in real time?  Example, two uses access the calendar at the same time.  User one reserves the resource on a certain day at 10:00am.  User two also want the reserve the resource at the same time.  To me it would seem that user two would get an error returned to them but would the calendar refresh to show user one's reservation when the error returned?

Comment: It's as real-time as can be at the time of reloading the page. The pages won't reload automatically, so if a user sits on it for 5 minutes and another user makes changes, the first user won't see the changes until they hit refresh. As far as errors are concerned, that'll depend on how your application handles two requests on the same time for the same resources.